# JSP page without HTML code for exporting data to Excel Sheet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, csv

I am facing a problem in exporting my data to excel sheet, this is because of some code which other developers in my team made. So the main problem is to export the data to Excel or .cvs using JSP page but without using any HTML code.
Any suggestion would also help me to explore in my developing arena. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 16):

Better use a Servlet for this. Raw Java code doesn't belong in a JSP file, that's simply recipe for [maintenance trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202).

To start, create a simple Java utility class which takes for example a `List<List<T>>` or a `List<Data>` (wherein `Data` represents one row) representing the CSV contents and an `OutputStream` as method arguments and write logic which does the data copying task.

Once you get that to work, create a Servlet class which takes some CSV file identifier as request parameter or pathinfo (I recommend using pathinfo as a certain webbrowser developed by a team in Redmond would fail on detection of filename/mimetype otherwise), uses the identifier to get the `List<List<T>>` or `List<Data>` from somewhere and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the `HttpServletResponse` along a set of correct response headers.

Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
public static <T> void writeCsv (List<List<T>> csv, char separator, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8"));
    for (List<T> row : csv) {
        for (Iterator<T> iter = row.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            String field = String.valueOf(iter.next()).replace("\"", "\"\"");
            if (field.indexOf(separator) > -1 || field.indexOf('"') > -1) {
                field = '"' + field + '"';
            }
            writer.append(field);
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                writer.append(separator);
            }
        }
        writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.flush();
}
```

Here's an example how you could use it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<List<String>> csv = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    csv.add(Arrays.asList("field1", "field2", "field3"));
    csv.add(Arrays.asList("field1,", "field2", "fie\"ld3"));
    csv.add(Arrays.asList("\"field1\"", ",field2,", ",\",\",\""));
    writeCsv(csv, ';', System.out);
}
```

And inside a Servlet you can basically do:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String filename = request.getPathInfo();
    List<List<Object>> csv = someDAO().list();
    response.setHeader("content-type", "text/csv");
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    writeCsv(csv, ',', response.getOutputStream());
}
```

Map this servlet on something like `/csv/*` and invoke it as something like `http://example.com/context/csv/filename.csv`. That's basically all. The filename in the pathinfo is important because a certain webbrowser developed by a team in Redmond ignores the `filename` part of the `Content-Disposition` header and uses the last path part of the URL instead.

Comment: definately a job for a servlet. +1

Comment: I tried a solution similar to this but I had problems getting the file through https. 

Why could it fail through https?.

Comment: The problem lies somewhere else. Ask your own question by pressing `Ask Question` button at right top and elaborate the problem in detail.