# JSP response content type Excel

Tags: excel, jsp, types, response

when i set response content type is excel. In excel sheet it is dsiplaying 1-Jan instead-of 1-1.
here is code snippet

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
%>
<table><tr><td>1-1</td></tr></table>
```

Appending single quote "'" will work. is there any other solution to set cell format or correct text?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Apache POI project to return an Excel file to the output stream, which will allow you to do proper data/cell formatting.

See http://poi.apache.org/

Would that work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You're fooling the webbrowser and Excel with a plain HTML table with a wrong content type and you're complaining that it doesn't work well in Excel due to an Excel-specific behaviour?

That doesn't sound right.

If you want an Excel file, create a real Excel file, not a plain HTML table along with a wrong content type. You can use the aforementioned [Apache POI HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) or Andy Khan's [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) for this.

As an alternative you can always go ahead with CSV. Less opaque and more easy. You can find here an example I recently posted: [JSP page without HTML code for exporting data to Excel Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755509/jsp-page-without-html-code-for-exporting-data-to-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

I got quick workqround is

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
%>
<table>
<tr><td style='mso-number-format:"\@";'>1-1< /td></tr>
</table>
```

We are planning to use poi api.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Now you're applying an Excel-version-specific workaround? You really need to hurry with POI.