# How to export <table> content (which is inside a one <div >) into excel by JSP

Tags: excel, jsp, apache-poi, export-to-excel, poi-hssf

I have developed a web application using JSP which creates a page with 
several page elements and a  with multiple records.
I wanted to export the content in that  into an excel file.

I used the code

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
        + "excel.xls");
```

as described in this article http://www.quicklyjava.com/export-web-page-to-excel/

But it exports the whole page. 
How can a export only the content in that particular table?

I cannot use the Apache POI library since i have to format(text colors,cell colors) the content in the JSP. And i need the same formatting in the excel file.

Can somebody help me with this? :)

Comment: You can just *move* the table into a new page and set the content type to `application/vnd.ms-excel` in it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524143/how-can-i-export-tables-to-excel-from-a-webpage

Comment: @Luiggi : I have to keep the other elements in the page. Cannot use a separate page with just the table. It's against the requirement. :(

Comment: You asked to *export* the table content into an Excel file, so you can use a button i.e. `<input type="submit" value="Export to Excel" />` to call the page with the Excel content type and the table content, nothing else. In this way, your initial page keeps intact and your new page contains the same table/data.

Comment: @Rachel : I read that question but it doesn't have the answer for exporting only the content of a table.

Comment: @Luiggi: I'm new to JSP. Can you explain it more?It would be a great help! :)

Comment: Before to post an answer, please tell me: 1) Are you using any MVC Framework like Spring 3, Struts 2, JSF 2 or other or plain JSP/Servlets? 2) Are you using jQuery or another js library in your project/web pages?

Comment: I'm using Struts 2. Yes there are few js libraries(including jQuery) i use in my project.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763964/jsp-response-content-type-excel/1764035#1764035 In other words, don't fool Excel. Just do it the right way.

Comment: @BalusC: Thankxx! I tried  Apache POI HSSF but i think it doesn't allow formatiing the cells(font colors,Cell colours etc) does it?

Comment: Yup, POI will happily let you format the text, control the colours and fonts etc

Comment: Thank you @Gagravarr POI HSSF library let us do most of the formatting to the excel sheet.
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api
Examples
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found a way to export only a single table in a page.
But the intended task(create a excel sheet with formatted data) can be done by Apache POI HSSF library

Here are the links to learn how to & examples - 
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html