# How to change to Excel format when downloading data from a JSP page to Excel?

Tags: java, excel, jsp, servlets

I am getting the result set in servlet and then forwarding to the JSP page where I put all data from resultset to table and then getting output to excel file. in the top of my JSP page I have

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;");

filename="Report";
filename+=".xls";
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+filename);
```

The problem is it is downloading data in excel sheet but default as web page so whenever i download the data i have to manually change the save as type to Excel workbook. and also when i download to excel it is warning me that file is not in XLS format whether you want to open it not.

Is there any way I can do like whenever I download the data in excel it will say Excel workbook in save as type?

Comment: Depending on your excel version, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files

Comment: well i am able to download on excel but only problem is it is giving me warnings that the file i am downloading which is 'report.xls' is in different format then excel. and after i save clicking ok it is giving me excel file with default save as type 'web page'

Comment: See response http://stackoverflow.com/a/1764035/33622

Answer (score 0):

```
Use response.setHeader() instead of response.addHeader()
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.xls");
```