# Export HTML table to Excel - using jQuery or Java

Tags: java, jquery, html, excel, jsp

I've a HTML table on my JSP page, that I want to be exported to Excel on a button click.

What would be the best way of going about this?

(For ex., how would I do this using may be a jQuery function?)

Any code examples for demo purposes should be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), we've been using it for years, never had any problems.

Alot of examples online to get a good start, and the documentation on the site is also good: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Answer (score 4):

Rather export to [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format. It's supported by Excel as well. Exporting to a fullworthy XLS(X) format using for example [Apache POI HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) or [JExcepAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) is slow and memory hogging.

Exporting to CSV is relatively simple. You can find a complete code example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755509/jsp-page-without-html-code-for-exporting-data-to-excel-sheet/1755605#1755605).

---

As to exporting to files using JavaScript, this is not possible without interaction of Flash or the server side. In Flash there's as far only the [Downloadify](http://downloadify.info/) library which can export to simple txt files. Further, ExtJs seems to have a [CSV export library](http://edspencer.net/2009/11/ext-ux-exporter-export-any-grid-to-excel-or-csv.html), but I can't find any feasible demo page.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the table using a library like http://jsoup.org/

After you get the data, you can store it in Excel-compatible format (CSV), or using Java Excel library for that like POI, or using JDBC to write data into Excel sheet, see this example:
[Password Protected Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609301/password-protected-excel-file/2609535#2609535)

Answer (score 1):

Excel can load CSV (comma-separated value) files, which are basically just files with everything that would go into separate Excel cells separated by comma.

I don't know enough about how jQuery can handle pushing information into a file that you would download, but it seems a jQuery library has been written that at least transforms html tables to CSV format, and it is here:
http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php

*Edit (February 29, 2016):*
You can use the table2csv implementation above in conjunction with [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) (which is a wrapper for the HTML5 W3C `saveAs()` spec).

The usage will end up looking something like:

```
var resultFromTable2CSV = $('#table-id').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});

var blob = new Blob([resultFromTable2CSV], {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});

saveAs(blob, 'desiredFileName.csv');
```

Answer (score 1):

I also spend lot of time to convert html to excel after lot of R & D i found following easiest way.

1. create hidden field and in that pass your html data to your servlet or controller for e.g

   ```
   <form id="formexcel" action="" method="post" name="formexcel">
       <input type="hidden" name="exceldata" id="exceldata" value="" />
   </form>
   ```
2. on your button of href click call following function and pass your html data using in  document.formexcel.exceldata.value and your servlet or controller in document.formstyle.action

   ```
   function exportDivToExcel() {
       document.formexcel.exceldata.value=$('#htmlbody').html();
       $("#lblReportForPrint").html("Procurement operation review report");
       document.formstyle.method='POST';
       document.formstyle.action='${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/generateexcel';
       document.formstyle.submit();
   }
   ```
3. Now in your controller or servlet write following code

   ```
   StringBuilder exceldata = new StringBuilder();
   exceldata.append(request.getParameter("exceldata"));
   ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
   response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"exportexcel.xls\"");
   outputStream.write(exceldata.toString().getBytes());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to Excel file format with JQuery is impossible.

You can try with Java. There are a lot of libraries to do that.

Comment: No, thats not true. It is absolutely possible!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create something on the server-side (like a servlet) to read the html and create the excel file and serve it back to the user.

You could use [this library](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) to help you do the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to try http://code.google.com/p/gwt-table-to-excel/, at least the server part.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the jQuery plugin [table2excel](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel). It works very well and no serverside coding is needed.

Using it is easy. Simply include jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now include the table2excel script (Remember to change the src destination to match yours)

```
<script src="dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
```

Now simply call the script on the table you want exportet.

```
$("#yourHtmTable").table2excel({
    exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
    name: "Worksheet Name",
    filename: "SomeFile" //do not include extension
});
```

It's also easy to attach to a button like so:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#table2excel").table2excel({
    // exclude CSS class
    exclude: ".noExl",
    name: "Excel Document Name"
    }); 
});
```

All examples are taken directly from the authors github page and from [jqueryscript.net](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html)