# How to wrap values of a row into new line at specific character in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have a sample dataframe with values:

```
data <- structure(list(A = c("Date)", "Values"), B = c("2023-04-03", "Heat Capacity\nSpecific Heat Capacity\nHeat Index" )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))
```

Here the 2nd row of last column extends to the right. I want the each values to be in new line without adding new rows.

My desired output:

[image]

The above table is created using `gt()`:

```
library(gt)
data %>%   
mutate(b = str_replace_all(b, "\n", "<br>")) %>%    
gt() %>%    
fmt_markdown(columns = TRUE)
```

But this is not useful as my final desired output I want is in  xlsx file and using `gt()` wouldn't work.
Is it possible to do anything with `dplyr` and `stringr` to achieve this similar result

Comment: so what specifically are you wanting? Because I took your example input, exported it using writexl, and importing it into Google Sheets, my spreadsheet looks identical to the gt output you wanted

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: @Mark - But when I output it using `writexl`, its similar to the dataframe

Comment: so the process is essentially 1. create the dataframe 2. export the dataframe 3. import the dataframe into Excel/Google Sheets. One or all of these could be not working correctly. Going backwards through these steps backwards is the best bet for debugging this

Comment: Okay, so debugging step #3, I uploaded my own output to Google Drive. Can you download it and open it and tell me if it gives you the correct output?  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17S1ng9jmWGpu5kdxaESQta5s7yQ89b41/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107688141380082141299&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @Mark Yes I can download it and the output is correct

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/240#top  I think `gt` tables to `xlsx` file is still in development

Comment: okay now try `structure(list(A = c("Date)", "Values"), B = c("2023-04-03", "Heat Capacity\nSpecific Heat Capacity\nHeat Index" )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" )) |> writexl::write_xlsx(path = "test.xlsx")`, then take the test.xlsx which is created, and open that, and tell me if that is rendered correctly

Comment: @Mark Nope didnt work

Comment: hmm that's really odd!! Because that is literally what I ran on mine to create the .xlsx file you opened

Comment: I think the problem I'm facing is due to how the reading the xlsx (Excel) file. When I attempted to read the file and display the output, it returned a lengthy row of values.  This output matches what is shown in the sample dataframe above.

`read_xlsx("file_name.xlsx", sheet = 1)`

Comment: @Mark I think the problem was with my Microsft Excel. When I try to open the excel in google sheets it showed me the correct format

Comment: odd! Unsure if this is a feature difference between Sheets and Excel, if something is wrong with your Excel, or it needs to be updated or what

Answer (score 1):

You can use package `gt` to format presentation quality tables.
See [this introduction to `gt`](https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/intro-creating-gt-tables.html).

Here is the code, output omitted.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(gt)
})

data <- structure(list(
  A = c("Date)", "Values"), 
  B = c("2023-04-03", "Heat Capacity\nSpecific Heat Capacity\nHeat Index" )), 
  row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))

data %>%
  mutate(B = gsub("\\n", "<br>", B)) %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns = everything())
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

You can export to a HTML file and open the file in Excel:

- [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-csv-htm-or-text-file-b62efe49-4d5b-4429-b788-e1211b5e90f6),
- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566350/converting-html-to-excel).

```
data %>%
  mutate(B = gsub("\\n", "<br>", B)) %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns = everything()) %>%
  as_raw_html() %>%
  writeLines(con = "~/Temp/so.html")
```

Comment: From here, How do you convert it into Excel file. I tried write_xlsx() but it gave an error

Comment: @Golem See if the edit solves it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need this in an XLSX file  because the main logic resides within a Shiny app. This app takes an Excel file, manipulates it, and then returns the manipulated XLSX file