# How to use JSP/JSTL to create a CSV file

Tags: java, jsp, csv, jstl, export-to-excel

I have created a jsp file, with a simple table on it.

I would like to create another jsp file that users can open in Excel or save as an xls.

This is my entire jsp file, this creates a csv file which opens in Excel when a link is clicked:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt"uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<% response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + "online-dashboard.csv" ); %>

<jsp:useBean id="ReportInfo" class="com.reports.ReportLister"  scope="request" />
${ReportInfo.reportType},M,W,Other
<c:forEach var="rrow" items="${ReportInfo.list}"  varStatus="rowCounter">
    ${rrow.subjectCode},${rrow.MCount},${rrow.WCount},${rrow.OCount}
</c:forEach>
Totals,${ReportInfo.totalMSections},${ReportInfo.totalWSections},${ReportInfo.totalOSections}
```

When I open it in Excel, each row is separated by 2 lines.

Is there an easy way to create an excel file this way?

Is there an easy way to add some formatting ( like bold text for the column headers )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **easy way** is to use the fact that Excel can understand HTML. So simply format your data as an HTML Table and send it as an XLS file. Something like

```
<table>
<c:forEach var="rrow" items="${ReportInfo.list}"  varStatus="rowCounter">
<tr><td><b>${rrow.subjectCode}</b></td>
    <td>${rrow.MCount}</td>
    <td>${rrow.WCount}</td>
    <td>${rrow.OCount}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is just the simple trick that I was looking for.  I set the header to use a filename ending in xsl, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be Spring and its [JExcelView](http://zhoupengylx.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-jexcel-with-spring-3-on.html).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting empty lines is that JSP is rendering empty lines inside your loop.  You could eliminate them by packing your loop into one line:

```
<c:forEach var="rrow" items="${ReportInfo.list}"  varStatus="rowCounter">${rrow.subjectCode},${rrow.MCount},${rrow.WCount},${rrow.OCount}</c:forEach>
```

Or you could add a servlet filter that would strip empty lines from the response.

However, if you want to add special formatting, I believe that goes beyond the comma-separated values format, and you'd need to generate excel native files as suggested by others.

**EDIT:** Instead of packing your loop into one line, try adding the following directive to your page:

```
<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a .xls file, you'll need something heavier-duty than JSTL.  [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) are two open-source libraries for generating native Excel format files.  POI can generate both .xls and .xlsx; I don't have experience with JExcelApi, but it appears to only support .xls.

As duffymo alluded to, Spring has an [AbstractExcelView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/view.html#view-document-configsubclasses) which you can extend and use with either library.  If you're not using Spring, though, you can still use one of the libraries to generate a Workbook object and write its contents to the OutputStream of a ServletResponse.  They will also let you format your data in various ways (including bold text) and even create comments and other Excel elements.

For a .xls file you'll want to set the content-type to `application/vnd.ms-excel`, and for .xlsx `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

Comment: I recommend JExcelAPI over POI (in my not-terribly-recent experience it uses far less memory), though they're both pretty solid.

Comment: According to the Spring docs, "We've found that the JExcelApi is somewhat more intuitive and furthermore, JExcelApi has a bit better image-handling capabilities. There have been memory problems with large Excel file when using JExcelApi however."  I found this in the spring 2.0 documentation, which may be more or less current than your experience.

Comment: Andy Khan's JExcel is indeed far superior to POI.  That's what Spring is using for its ExcelView.

Answer (score 0):

JSP is not entirely the right tool for this. Use a servlet class. To save some bytes in Stackoverflow's database, here's just a link to an answer I posted before on the subject: [Export to excel using JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755509/jsp-page-without-html-code-for-exporting-data-to-excel-sheet/1755605#1755605).

---

That said, I have a few comments on your code and the other answers:

1. Do not use XLS content type when returning CSV. This will lead to warnings during opening the file. Use the CSV content type: `text/csv`. Excel perfectly understands this.
2. Do not render HTML along a wrong content type (the one indicating a XLS(X) file). You're then basically fooling Excel. Since Excel version 2007, it will display warnings about that.

Comment: I wouldn't quite say that Excel "perfectly understands" CSV. It seems to behave well enough with ASCII CSV, but it barfs on non-ASCII UTF-8. It will accept tab-delimited (not comma-delimited) UTF-16 with BOM. It's a bit of a mess, and LibreOffice is considerably better.