# Using JSP to download a file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am currently trying to use JSP to build some small litle apps and have not got stuck on something, downloading files from a webserver. I just cant seem to work out how I should go about this task.

Are there any JSP developers here who know to go about this and could point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP page without HTML code for exporting data to Excel Sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755509/jsp-page-without-html-code-for-exporting-data-to-excel-sheet)

Comment: You'd get much better answers if you rephrase your question and be more specific about what advice you need

Comment: What I mean is, what classes would be used to download files, Its not necessarily a CSV file, it could be anything, But how do i go about downloading files from a server using Java

Comment: I removed the CSV ambiguity from your question since it's apparently not specifically about CSV files.

Comment: Go through this link...It may help you....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678094/what-should-be-the-content-type-to-download-any-file-format-in-jsp

Answer (score 7):

If the resource is static, just put it in the public webcontent (there where your JSP/HTML/CSS/JS/etc files also are) and include a link to it in your JSP.

```
<a href="file.ext">download</a>
```

The servletcontainer will worry about setting the right HTTP response headers.

If the resource is dynamic, create a servlet which obtains an `InputStream` of the content somehow (`new FileInputStream`, `resultSet.getBinaryStream()`, etc..etc..) and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the response along at least the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` response headers. Finally just link to that servlet in your JSP.

```
<a href="fileservlet/file.ext">download</a>
```

You can find a basic example in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html).

The `Content-Type` header informs the client about the content type of the file so that it knows what application it should use to open it. The `Content-Disposition` header informs the client what to do with it, displaying it inline or saving as attachment.

Comment: that would be the millionth question about file download with servlets/jsp :) +1 anyway