# java error code.please check in (java)

Tags: java, syntax-error

Please help check the code. Only I the beginner can write the corrected code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static List<String> getFileNames(File directory, String extension) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        File[] total = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : total) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(extension)) {
                list.add(file.getName());
            }
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                List<String> tempList = getFileNames(file, extension);
                list.addAll(tempList);          
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException { 
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
        String myName = request.getParameter("text");
        List<String> files = getFileNames(new File("C:\\Users\\vany\\Desktop\\test"), "txt");
        for (String string : files) {
            if (myName.equals(string)) {
                try {
                    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\vany\\Desktop\\test\\" + string);
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
                    int b;
                    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
                    writer.print("<html>");
                    writer.print("<head>");
                    writer.print("<title>HelloWorld</title>");
                    writer.print("<body>");
                    writer.write("<div>");
                    while((b = reader.read()) != -1) {
                        writer.write((char) b);
                    }
                    writer.write("</div>");
                    writer.print("</body>");
                    writer.print("</html>");
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error may be here:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

And here:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
```

Comment: 1) *"The error may be here"*  Change that to `catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); 
System.exit(0);
}` and copy post the result as an edit to the question.  2) Fix the code formatting for the code.

Comment: Print the error stack by `catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();
System.exit(0);
}` and paste the error stack by editing your question.

Comment: please properly format your code before posting. It hurts my eyes

Comment: i'm sorry for making this code

Comment: can write already corrected the code I'm still a beginner in java

Comment: @user1790746 In order to see what is the reason for the error, you should add `ex.printStackTrace();` just above `System.exit(0);` and paste that error stack in your question, so that other people here could help to resolve your problem very fast. Regards

Comment: Can you do it, because every time you try to edit the code I have that does not work

Comment: For some reason this question is ending in chaos... why is it a community wiki now? To me this q&a does not seem to be helpful, so I voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should not use System.exit(0) in servlet.

I would suggest you to read this first

[About servlets in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005873/using-jsp-to-download-a-file)

Then here is a file downloading example by BalusC

[Serve your files](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/07/fileservlet.html)

Once you understand the concepts, you can fly with servlets. All the best.

Comment: With catch understand you can set:

    e.printStackTrace();

and

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);

We must then prescribe

    finally {
      close(reader);
      }

Comment: still on the screen does not print

Comment: @user1790746 any error ? did u remove and put pritstacktrace() ?

Comment: I made it.to tell you that I brought