# What should be the content type to download any file format in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to make a provision to download all file types...Is there any way to download any file format in jsp...

My code snippet:

```
    String filename = (String) request.getAttribute("fileName");        
    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    String disHeader = "Attachment";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);

    // transfer the file byte-by-byte to the response object
    File fileToDownload = new File(filename);
    response.setContentLength((int) fileToDownload.length());
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
    int i = 0;
    while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(i);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
```

If I specify setContentType as APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM, pdf, text, doc files are getting downloaded.... But the problem is with image files...

What is problem with image files? I want to download all image file types...

I searched similar questions but could not find proper answer...
Thanks...

Comment: Try, `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);`

Comment: There's [a whole smattering of image mime types](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml), and it pays to be specific.

Comment: @AVD: I tried that...it doesnt help :(

Comment: I found out that some extra lines are appended to the file in the beginning...I figured it out when i compared the original text file with the downloaded text file...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I somehow managed to do this...
The problem is with JSP's "Out.write", which is not capable of writing byte stream...

I replaced jsp file with servlet...

The code snippet is:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String filename = (String) request.getAttribute("fileName");
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment;filename="+filename);

        File file = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        //copy binary contect to output stream
        while(fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, (int)file.length()) != -1)
        {
        out.write(outputByte, 0, (int)file.length());
        }
     }
```

Now I can download all types of files....

Thanks for the responces :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the following link ,

[JSP download - application/octet-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936615/jsp-download-application-octet-stream)

Might help you to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

for images you should use setContentType(image/jpg).you can checkout this link for mime types

http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm